# Save File Dialog with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to ask if there is any lines of code that I can put in a JS file to pop up a file dialog and prompt me to save a txt file that was created?

Currently, using ember.js in my project. The sequence of action are clicking a button in the webpage will tigger an action to call a function in one of my js file.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

Comment: You're gonna need to use PHP and AJAX for this if you don't want to use Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Because of normal browser security limitations, you cannot use JavaScript to save a file to the desktop from a web browser so in short the answer is no you can't.

I have made the assumption you are generating text to be saved to a file in the Web Browser. What you can do is submit that text to your web server and have your web server send the text back as the HTTP response but setting the following HTTP Header...

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>
```

... which will force the Save As dialog, instead of the browser rendering it on screen.

Reference: http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html

Hope that helps you...

Comment: In case you're looking for the code to change the `content-disposition` in Rails, [search the internet](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/99503)